# In Windows, What Makes qmake Append a "d" to a Debug Target?

Tags: windows, qt, qmake

I'm using a provided `.pro` file and for some reason, it's configured so that the debug libraries do not have "d" appended to their library name. What causes this and how do I restore it?

E.g. `QtGui4.dll` (release) and `QtGuid4.dll` (debug)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to the .pro file and it will append **_debug** for mac and a **d** for windows debug build.

```
 CONFIG += debug_and_release

 CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
     mac: TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,_debug) 
     win32: TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)
 }
```

`CONFIG(xx, yy)` This function can be used to test for variables placed into the CONFIG variable
`join(variablename, glue, before, after)`  Joins the value of variablename with glue, before and after.

[Installing in Both Modes](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-common-projects.html#installing-in-both-modes)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think Qt does this automatically with some configuration. I'm not looking to explicitly add this myself.

Comment: As far as I know Qt doesn't do it automatically and you'll have to add it yourself. See the link "Installing in Both Modes"

Comment: What about Linux -_d is not necessary? Can I build with?

Comment: The `d` is never a necessity. It is just a way to make the type of build for the given library known to the user who links against it. If you build your application in release mode yet link against a library built in debug mode (and vice versa), you might get some very nasty surprises along the way.

Answer (score 1):

In your .pro file, add `debug` to the `CONFIG` variable:

```
CONFIG += qt debug
```

See: http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qmake-tutorial.html#making-an-application-debuggable